# apache camel with quartz and custom component with from endpoint

Tags: apache-camel

I am developing custom camel component.  It has only Consumer support means it can be called in **from endpoint only**. Let's assume my custom component registered with 'mycomp' scheme.

**Req 1:** We have use case where we need to support below route.

from("mycomp:Something").to("file:data/outbox");

Above route is working as I have provided endpoint with the implementation of createConsumer()

**Req 2:** Now, we have another requirement to start above route at specific time. (assume every day at 08:00 AM)

For Req2, I have decided to use camel-quartz component.  As we know, quartz also support **only from endpoint** and from endpoint for my req2 will be like ..

from("quartz://myTimer?cron=0+0+8+*+*+*")

**Now, the Problem:**

My custom component need from() endpoint and it also need to trigger at specific time. But quartz also works with from() endpoint only.  In Camel I can NOT have route with two from like .. from("xxx").from("yyy") ..

**One of the workaround:**

I can develop processor which start route defined for "mycomp" and final route will be something like ..

from("quartz://myTimer?cron=0+0+8+*+*+*").process(ProcessorWhich_**StartsMyRoute**);

from("mycomp:Something").**noAutoStartup**().**routeId**("**MyRoute**").to("file:data/outbox");

But again I need to come up with processor which stops MyRoute at specific time using quartz scheduling .. it will be something like ..

from("quartz://myTimerStop?cron=0+30+8+*+*+*").process(ProcessorWhich_**StopsMyRoute**);

Above, I am stopping at 8:30 AM. But this is the limitation with this solution and in real life I don't know what is the safe time to stop MyRoute.

Please share your ideas/input on how to achieve both Req1 and Req2.
Please ask if you need further details on my usecase.

Answer (score 0):

**Second workaround/solution:**

Meanwhile, I have found another way to achieve this.

I have developed a processor which first call suspendRoute() and then immediately call resumeRoute() methods for route with 'mycomp' scheme .. something like below ..

**Routes:**

from("quartz://myTimer?cron=0+0+8+*+*+*").process(ProcessorWhich_**SuspendResumeMyRoute**);

from("mycomp:Something").noAutoStartup().routeId("MyRoute").to("file:data/outbox");

**Processor**

```
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        CamelContext ctx = exchange.getContext();
        ctx.suspendRoute(routeName);
        ctx.resumeRoute(routeName);
    }
```

Now, out of above two; the second one looks more closer to ideal solution. **Can any one share what it takes (wrt performance and design) to suspend() and resume() route as above.** With second solution, MyRoute will start on 8:00 AM and second day again on 8:00 AM it's first suspend and then resume and on third day again on 8:00 AM .. suspend followed by resume.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a cron-sheduled route policy, maybe?

Here is a useful link - [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/cronscheduledroutepolicy.html)

Just create a new policy, set start time or stop time or whatever you want to and then add the policy to your route.

For eg;

```
CronScheduledRoutePolicy yourPolicy = new CronScheduledRoutePolicy();

//set start time etc on your policy 

    from("mycomp:Something").routePolicy(yourPolicy).
    noAutoStartup().
    routeId("MyRoute").
    to("file:data/outbox");
```

Comment: thanks for your idea.  I didn't evalute the option throughly as we have decided something to go with from(quartz).to(mycomp).to(file) route pattern.  Here is my view on your suggestion, I think CronScheduleRoutePolicy will just allow to start route once and will work with if given route is schedule to start at given time (using cron). But, I want to trigger this route multiple time so I again need to stop it and start it again.